# How can i multiple table combining with Laravel?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

For example ;

```
 $hall_templates = HallTemplate::where('hall_id' , $id)->orderBy('order' , 'ASC')->get();
```

Output:

```
 [{"id":16,"hall_id":3,"template_name":"Magazin Outlet","order":1,"width":12,"height":12},
  {"id":17,"hall_id":3,"template_name":"Merinos K\u00fclt\u00fcr Merkezi","order":2,"width":22,"height":12}]
```

For example second table info as below;

```
$armchair_number_count = HallTemplateArmChair::where('template_id' , 16)->get();
```

Output:

```
[{"id":1,"template_id":16,"armchair_no":"a1"}, 
 {"id":2,"template_id":16,"armchair_no":null}]
```

how can i combine these two tables.
I want to do output:

```
array({"id":16,"hall_id":3,"template_name":"Magazin Outlet","order":1,"width":12,"height":12, "armchair_number_count",2},
{"id":17,"hall_id":3,"template_name":"Merinos K\u00fclt\u00fcr Merkezi","order":2,"width":22,"height":12, "armchair_number_count",0);
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: did u defined any relationships for those two models?

Comment: I did not define relationships.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`withCount()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models) method:

```
HallTemplate::withCount('armchairNumber')->where('hall_id' , $id)->orderBy('order' , 'ASC')->get();
```

This method will count chairs and will add `armchair_number_count` property to each `HallTemplate` object.

To make it work, define the relationship in the `HallTemplate` model:

```
public function armchairNumber()
{
    return $this->hasMany(HallTemplateArmChair::class, 'template_id');
}
```

Comment: "armchair_number_count":144(false)

Comment: "armchair_number_count":2(should be)

Comment: @ufuk this means you have 144 chairs with `template_id = $id`

Comment: how to count find with  "armchair_no":"a1" column. where('armchair_no' , '!=' ,null)

Comment: @ufuk in the example above you're ignoring `armchair_no`, so it's not clear what exactly are you trying to achieve. To ignore `null` use the closure `withCount(['armchairNumber' => function($q) { $q->where('armchair_no', '!=', null); }])`

Comment: Bro sorry but take error message function($q) { $q->where('armchair_no', '!=', null); }

Comment: mb_strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

Comment: @ufuk please double check all the code from the 5th comment. If it still doesn't work, please show the full code you're trying to use now.

Comment: Again control code 5th comment. WORKED. You are SUPER DEVELOPER:)